# DB communication suggestion for web/mobile apps

Tags: android, web-applications, database, intel-xdk

I have a lot of nice ideas to develop into Web and Mobile applications, most of them need an online DB communication. However, I don't know nothing how to configure a fresh DB server from the scratch and start queries and requesting it. Even with DB basis acquired during my graduation.

What I don't know is what to use. If I need a DBMS or build my own server from scratch (which I would like to avoid to save time).

So, I don't want to develop a DB server (back-end, such as PhP, Java, etc...). I need a ready-to-use back-end to send my queries and request to it.

Any suggestion, or tutorial how to configure it? Like deploying on AWS...

many thanks, in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

I've developed some card game apps that use databases for leaderboards and multiplayer data. I found that using http to access php scripts which in turn access mySQL databases and json encode the result certainly works and is reliable. You will need to write a bit of php and set up the databases but other than that it's quite straightforward. If you keep your http access in a seperate thread in the app you can do visual and input processing whilst waiting for the result.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to build database server yourself. Database services are available from some companies. Some are:

1. Amazon Relational Database Service ([Amazon RDS](http://aws.amazon.com/rds/))
2. Google [Cloud SQL](https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/)
3. Windows Azure SQL Database ([SQL Azure](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/services/sql-database/))
4. [Clear DB](https://www.cleardb.com/)